# Account for instance variable set by session value in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I am trying to test a 'post create' action in a controller. During 'create', in the controller, I assign a variable whose values modify the new record before that record is saved. That variable, @trip, is created from a session value that I can't seem to account for.

So my question is, given what I am trying to test, what is the best way (or any way) to account for an instance variable in a controller when that variable is set by a session value?

**Error message:**

```
OrderItemsController POST create with valid attributes creates a new order item
Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, order_item: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:order_item) }.to change(OrderItem,:count).by(1)
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `company_id' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:29:in `create'
 # ./spec/controllers/order_items_controller_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Controller spec:**

```
describe "POST create action" do
    let(:trip)              { create(:trip)}
    let(:trip_date)         { create(:trip_date) }
    let(:buyer)             { create(:buyer) }
    let(:company)           { create(:company) }
    let(:order_item)        { attributes_for(:order_item, trip_date_id: trip_date.id, buyer_id: buyer.id, company_id: company.id) }
    let(:bad_order_item)    { attributes_for(:bad_order_item, trip_date_id: trip_date.id, buyer_id: buyer.id, company_id: company.id) }

    context "given valid order item attributes" do
        it "creates a new order item" do
            expect{ post :create, { order_item: order_item, trip_id: trip.id } }.to change(OrderItem, :count).by(1)
        end
    end
end
```

**Error references line 29 of my order_items_controller.rb, where the variable comes in:**

```
line 25:    def create
line 26:        @trip = Trip.find_by_id(session[:current_trip_id])
line 27:        @order_item = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)
line 28:        @order_item.buyer_id            = current_user.id
> line 29:      @order_item.company_id          = @trip.company_id
line 30:        @order_item.first_person_cost   = @trip.first_person_cost
line 31:        @order_item.second_person_cost  = @trip.second_person_cost

line 32:        if @order_item.save
line 33:            redirect_to cart_path(current_user), notice: 'New order item created.'
line 34:        else
line 35:            render 'new', notice: 'Unable to create new order item.'
line 36:        end    
line 37:    end
```

**OTHER ATTEMPTS**

b. I have also tried:

```
    let(:trip_date)         { create(:trip_date) }
    let(:buyer)             { create(:buyer) }
    let(:company)           { create(:company) }
    let(:order_item)        { attributes_for(:order_item, trip_date_id: trip_date.id, buyer_id: buyer.id, company_id: company.id) }
    let(:bad_order_item)    { attributes_for(:bad_order_item, trip_date_id: trip_date.id, buyer_id: buyer.id, company_id: company.id) }

    describe "POST create" do
        let(:trip)     {create(:trip) }
        context "with valid attributes" do
            it "creates a new order item" do
              Trip.stub_chain(:friendly, :find_by_id).and_return(trip)
              expect{ post :create, order_item: order_item }.to change(OrderItem,:count).by(1)
              end
          end
        end
    end
```

Resulting in the same error.

c. I have also tried

```
describe "POST create action" do
    let(:trip)              { create(:trip) }
    let(:trip_date)         { create(:trip_date) }
    let(:buyer)             { create(:buyer) }
    let(:company)           { create(:company) }
    let(:order_item)        { attributes_for(:order_item, trip_date_id: trip_date.id, buyer_id: buyer.id, company_id: company.id) }
    let(:bad_order_item)    { attributes_for(:bad_order_item, trip_date_id: trip_date.id, buyer_id: buyer.id, company_id: company.id) }

    context "given valid order item attributes" do
        it "creates a new order item" do
            expect{ post :create, order_item: order_item, trip_id: trip.id }.to change(OrderItem, :count).by(1)
        end
    end
end
```

Resulting in the same error.

d. I have also tried:

```
    describe "POST create action" do
        let(:trip_date)         { create(:trip_date) }
        let(:buyer)             { create(:buyer) }
        let(:company)           { create(:company) }
        let(:bad_order_item)    { attributes_for(:bad_order_item, trip_date_id: trip_date.id, buyer_id: buyer.id, company_id: company.id) }

        context "given valid order item attributes" do
            it "creates a new order item" do
            Trip.stub_chain(:friendly, :find_by_id).and_return(trip)
            order_item = attributes_for(:order_item, trip_date_id: trip_date.id, buyer_id: buyer.id, company_id: company.id)
            expect{ post :create, order_item: order_item }.to change(OrderItem, :count).by(1)
        end
    end
```

Resulting in:

```
1) OrderItemsController POST create action given valid order item attributes creates a new order item
    Failure/Error: Trip.stub_chain(:friendly, :find_by_id).and_return(trip)
    NameError:
        undefined local variable or method `trip' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::OrderItemsController_2::POSTCreateAction::GivenValidOrderItemAttributes:0x0000010154d5d8>
        # ./spec/controllers/order_items_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any help is appreciated. It's been a couple weeks. Thanks.

Comment: Line 26 is missing ]. No doubt it's there in the original. d is just because you didn't define trip in the test. I'd remove that one from your question. For the rest, you need to debug. Put logging or a breakpoint in your controller to see what `params[:trip_id]` and `Trip.friendly` are and maybe you'll learn something.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Line 26 is what I can't account for in the tests. Is that what you mean by missing? And are you saying my attempts other than d are generally on the right track?

Comment: In line 26, `:trip_id` should be followed by `]`

Comment: Got it. You actually said that clearly. Fixed the example typo.

Comment: Realized my question didn't include the fact that the variable is being pulled from sessions. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally googled the right terms, and found the Rails docs that discuss how to set session variables for each action. My solution looked like this:

```
expect{ post :create, {order_item: order_item}, {"current_trip_id" => trip.id}  }.to change(OrderItem, :count).by(1)
```

My salvation lay here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

```
expect{ post :create, order_item: order_item, trip_id: trip.id }
```

Try changing this to:

```
expect{ post :create, { order_item: order_item, trip_id: trip.id } }
```

`post` takes both a params hash and a session hash as arguments; all of the posted params should be in a single hash.

Comment: I've changed the code to match, but no dice. I've updated my code to show what I used in this attempt (attempt c, above)

Comment: Those two lines behave identically.